# Which or which of the following statements is true in XML?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, schema, dtd

> I think the answer is nr 2, but I am not sure. I also think that XML is case sensetive, could somone help?
>
> 1. An XML schema in the Document Type Definition (DTD) format can be described more expressively than a in the XML Schema Definition (XSD)
>      format.
> 2. An XML document must have one or more root elements.
> 3. A well-formatted XML document must follow a specified XML schema.
> 4. XML is case sensitive.
>
> This is a question from w3schools. Hope somone can help.

Comment: 1) entirely opinion-based; 2) exactly one root element, so false; 3) "well-formatted" is not a thing, it's "well-formed", but even so the statement is false; 4) true, it's case sensitive

Comment: hm.. I think the answer is 4 because all of an XML document is case-sensitive, am I right?

Comment: So the answer is 4 right?

Answer (score 0):

1. False, XSD can describe any constraint that can be expressed in a DTD, but the reverse is not true.
2. A document must have exactly one root element. Call that true or false depending on how you read the question.
3. False.
4. True.